# can I use abp backend with seperate angular project not the default abp-angular?

Tags: angular

I have an angular project that built with Angular CLI and now I want to use the abp as the backend. I dont want to use the abp-angular and just want to communicate with abp through HttpClient like a standard backend. Is it possible? Can you give a documentation or any instruction? Thanks.

I tried to send requests using built-in Angular's HttpClient. I've tried everything and failed.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.